# Unable to add item in Strapi project

Tags: node.js, strapi

while following link - 
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/getting-started/quick-start.html#create-your-first-api

I got stuck in an issue. I've created a productList in Content Type, added field names & their respective data-types. But, when I tried to add data into productList it is not working just showing loader.
[image: loader]

No error in terminal

[image: console log]

Comment: Hello, can you give us your Nodejs, npm and Strapi version.
And the database you use.
Did you migrate your application or it's a fresh new one using also a new database ?

Comment: strapi - '3.0.0-alpha.14.3', npm - '5.6.0', node - '8.11.3'.. yes it is fresh one.. just completed setup with help of above URL.

Comment: Facing same issue. 18.04 LTS | Node 11 | MongDB 4.0.5 | Nginx 1.14 | Strapi 3.0.0-alpha.18